# Interframe navigation using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know there are already a lot of Q&As regarding navigation using Jscript and JQuery.  But so far, I haven't seen a question involving interframe navigation. I already know how to make the user navigate in another site from the current site he/she in using `window.navigate` or `location.replace`, or if the user has one `iframe` and then navigate it, just specify the `target` attribute to the name of the `iframe`.

Rather, what I'm specifically referring to is that what if I have two `iframes`, say frame0 and frame1. On one frame, I have a 'Quit' link. When user clicks that, JS will navigate frame0 to one site then the other frame (frame1) to another site at the same time.

So, for example, the parent HTML has the two iframes:

Parent HTML:

```
<iframe width="75%" height="420px" src="first.html" name="frame0" frameBorder="1" id="zero">
<iframe width="75%" height="30px" src="bottom.html" name="frame1" frameBorder="1" id="first">
```

And frame1 contains bottom html which has the 'Quit' link.

Bottom HTML:

```
<a name="quit" id="quit">Quit</a>
```

**EDIT**

Now, I have this on the JQuery side on the parent HTML:

```
var link = $("#quit")[0];
$("#first").contents().find(link).on("click",function(){
    $("#zero").location.replace("menu.html");
    $("#first").location.replace("menu.html");
});
```

But the query didn't work. I actually got the idea here: http://api.jquery.com/contents/ and just changed a few things to fit what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on the parent window:

```
 $('body iframe.firstFrame').contents().find('button.quit').on('click',function(e) {
    frames[0].location.replace(...
    frames[1].location.replace(...
 });
```

or

```
 $('body iframe').first().contents().find
```

Comment: Okay. I checked it. Nothing happened. I even tried changing `button` to `a`  since the 'Quit' was a link and not a button. Or will this only work if it's a button? Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, the `firstFrame` supposedly refer to the frame where the 'Quit' link is, right? I also tried replacing it with frame1 (since the link was in frame1) and I still got nothing.

Comment: So you tried it with `.find('a.quit')`. Does the `a` have the class `quit`?  `.fristFrame` was referring to the first frame but try the 2nd option as well, `$('body iframe').first().contents().find...`

Comment: Ooh... so the `.quit` referred to the class. I thought it was the `name`. Wait, I'll try adding it.

Comment: I still got nothing. I added the class `quit` on the link and still none. I also tried both options already. I edited my question and posted the codes there for clarity. Thank you

Comment: Might be a typo but `<a class = quit name = quit>Quit</a>` needs to be `<a class="quit" name="quit">Quit</a>`

Comment: Hmm. Try this in parent:  $("iframe").first().ready(function () {$(frames[0].document).on("click", "a.quit", function(){
   ...
  });});

Comment: Hello @artm. Sorry if it took a while. I tried what you commented. It still didn't work. I even experimented a little and did something (I edited my question and moved the code block there). I actually got the idea here: [link](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). But then, that too didn't work

Comment: OK, let me try a few things.